# How to get temporary Permesso di Soggiorno?

Tags: germany, immigration, resident-permit, italy, international-law

I am renewing my Permesso di Soggiorno.

I want to travel to Germany for Christmas vacation to visit my sister, but I'm waiting for the renewal of my Permesso di Soggiorno to be complete

How to get temporary Permesso di Soggiorno?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 1):

Italy does not issue a temporary Permesso but allows you to travel (and re-enter) as follows, per the [**Polizia di Stato d'Italia**](http://www.sicurincitta.it/articolo/10722)

> **Requirements for immigrants leaving Italy temporarily**
>
> Foreigners awaiting **renewal of their residence permits** can leave and re-enter Italy if they hold:
>
> - the receipt issued by Italian Post offices (Poste Italiane S.p.A) certifying the submission of the application for renewal of their residence permit or EC residence permit for long-term residents;
> - the expired residence permit;
> - their passport or other equivalent travel document .